# how to calculate percentage based on added amount?

Tags: percentages

Example, I have 100 in the account and they give me an interest bonus of 2, that is, now I have 102 thanks to the interest they gave me. Is there a formula to know according to the amount they gave me? Here, because they are simple numbers, we can know that the percentage was 2%, that is, 0.02 * 100  I would like to know the percentage that was added to my account. I had an example of 1800 and they added 2.41 to have a total in my account of $1802.41

What mathematical formula can I use to find out what percentage that amount is based on the base amount, assuming interest was the same all the time?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hint: $\frac{102}{100}=1.02=1+0.02$.

Answer (score 0):

You can use: $\frac{new - old}{old}\times100\%$

$\frac{1802.41 -1800}{1800}\times100\% = 0.13389\%$

Comment: Oh cool! Thanks! simple and interesting! Did you use some method to interpret what you needed or was that formula already known?

Comment: It is a pretty well known formula. https://www.cuemath.com/percentage-increase-formula/